# Why Spurious Eigenvalues comes from mixed states?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, operator-theory

In this book [Many-Electron Approaches in Physics, Chemistry and Mathematics](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-06379-9)  they have the following definition at page 36

Definition 1 (Spurious spectrum) A real number $\lambda \in(-1,1)$ is called a spurious eigenvalue of $D^V$ (relative to the approximation scheme $W_n$ ), if there exists $\lambda_n$ in the spectrum of $\left(D^V\right)_{\mid W_n}$ converging to $\lambda$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, such that

- either $\lambda$ is not in the spectrum of $D^V$;
- or $\lambda$ is an isolated eigenvalue of finite multiplicity $M$ of $D^V$, but its multiplicity is overestimated in the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$. This means that there are more than $M$ eigenvalues of $\left(D^V\right)_{\mid W_n}$ counted with multiplicity in the interval $\left(\lambda-\varepsilon_n, \lambda+\varepsilon_n\right)$, for some $\varepsilon_n \rightarrow 0$.

in order to explain what Spurious Eigenvalues is they give the following example at page 37

We take $\mathfrak{H}=L^2(0,2 \pi)$ as Hilbert space and recall the Fourier basis
$$
\{1, \cos (n r), \sin (n r)\}_{n \geqslant 1} .
$$

So for $f(r)\in \mathfrak{H} $ we have
$$f(r)=\frac{a_0}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{n \geqslant 1} a_n \cos (n r)+b_n \sin (n r),$$

where
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi}|f(r)|^2 \mathrm{~d} r=\left|a_0\right|^2+\sum_{n \geqslant 1}\left|a_n\right|^2+\left|b_n\right|^2
$$
We now introduce the orthogonal projection $P$ onto the odd modes,
$$
(P f)(r)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{n \geqslant 1} b_n \sin (n r)
$$
the spectrum of this operator is $\operatorname{Spec}(P)=(0,1)$

Now we choose our approximation space $W_n$ by picking all the even and odd modes less or equal than $n-1$, and mixing the two $n$ modes as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
W_n=\operatorname{span}\left(1, \sin (r), \cos (r), \ldots, \sin ((n-1) r), \\
\cos ((n-1) r), \cos (\theta) \cos (n r)+\sin (\theta) \sin (n r)\right) .
\end{aligned} \tag 1
$$

In this basis the matrix $P_{\mid W_n}$  has only diagonal non zeros elements

$\operatorname{diag}(P_{\mid W_n})=(0,1,0,...,\sin^2 (\theta))$

and so the spectrum of $P_{\mid W_n}=(0,1,\sin^2 (\theta))$

and then they have

> This academic example reveals most of the nature of spectral
> pollution.A spurious mode is obtained when states from the spectrum
> above and below the considered gap are mixed together

But if  we choose the basis
$$
\begin{aligned}
U_n=\operatorname{span}\left(1, \sin (r), \cos (r), \ldots, \sin ((n-1) r), \\
\cos ((n-1) r), \sin (\theta) \sin (n r)\right) .
\end{aligned} \tag 2
$$
instead of $(1)$ we would obtain the same spectrum $\operatorname{Spec}(P_{\mid U_n})=(0,1,\sin^2 (\theta))$

I am not understanding why is the mixing of states that originates spurious states.

Comment: What is a "spurious mode"?

Comment: @
Qiaochu Yuan I will edit my question

Comment: Isn't $(Pf)(r)=\frac12(f(r)-f(2\pi-r))?$

Comment: @ 
Thomas Andrews what you mean by that?

Comment: Is $\theta$ a constant?  Or is $\theta$ any angle? Either way, it is not at all clear how the two bases span the same subspace, $W_n.$

Comment: In particular, the second span has all elements with $a_n=0.$

Comment: @ 
Thomas Andrews maybe is confusion in notation but I am not saying that the two basis span the same space . what I am saying that the matrix  operator  $P$ in this spaces have the same spectrum

Comment: Then you shouldnt use $W_n$ for both of them. Call the second $W_n',$ or some other letter.

Comment: What do you mean by “the matrix $P|_{W_n}$”? I mean, $P$ does not preserve $W_n$, right? So if you want to represent $P|_{W_n}$ with a matrix, you need a different basis for the codomain of the map. What is the second basis? And just to be clear, with tht symbol you mean the restriction of $P$ on $W_n$, right?

Comment: I am pretty sure in your second example the spectrum of $P|_{U_n}$ is $\{0,1\}$, without $\sin^2(\theta)$. The last element is odd, so is left invariant by $P$, so it corresponds to an eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: @ 
Lorenzo Pompili let $e_i \in W_n $ then $(P|_{W_n})_{ij}=(e_j,Pe_i)$ where $(e_j,e_i)$ denotes the internal product

Comment: Thank you, now it makes sense. So basically $(P|_{W_n})_{ij}$ is the matrix representing the operator $P’\circ P|{W_n}$ with respect to the selected basis, where $P’$ is the projection operator on $W_n$ if the basis is orthonormal.

Comment: @ Lorenzo Pompili yes

Comment: The “problem” with the basis $U_n$ is that is not orthonormal, in particular is not normalized. So it does not make sense to look at the eigenvalues of the matrix $(e_i,P|_{U_n}e_j)$: that is not something I would call “spectrum”, as it depends on the choice of the basis, not only on the space $U_n$ itself.

Comment: I mean, the spectrum of an operator roughly represents the scaling factor of the eigenfunctions when you apply the operator. It would not make sense if the spectrum of the operator $P|_{U_n}$ changed by varying $\theta$, since changing $\theta$ (in the case of the basis $U_n$) you would simply be rescaling the last eigenvector. So the spectrum cannot be $\{0,1,\sin^2(\theta)\}$.

Comment: @Lorenzo Pompili could you turn the your comment into  an answer in orde to close the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I’ll sum up what we discussed in the comments. First, we should clarify what we mean by the spectrum of $P|_{W_n}$, as if we define $P|_{W_n}$ as the restriction of $P$ over $W_n$, the domain and codomain are different. What we actually mean is the spectrum of $P’\circ P|_{W_n}$, where $P’$ is the projection operator onto the space $W_n$.

Now, from our discussion in the comments, the spectrum of $P|_{U_n}$ (so in the last example) is $\{0,1\}$, since all the eigenfunctions in the basis are either left invariant by $P$ or mapped to zero by $P$. I think you were confused because you wrote down a non orthonormal basis.

---

About the last line you wrote, I think the point is the following. Assume a general situation in which you restrict (approximate) a self-adjoint operator $A$ to a subspace $W$ of your Hilbert space $V$ (in your case $A$ is $P$, and $W$ is $W_n$). Then the spectrum of the operator $A|_W$ in general will not simply decrease: on the contrary, you could have some more spectrum coming from the approximation. The natural condition to impose on $W$ to avoid such phenomenon is that $A(W)\subset W$: in this case, it is immediate that $A$ also preserves $W^\perp$ and the spectrum of the restriction of $A$ to both spaces is contained in the full spectrum of $A$.

On the other hand, if you choose $W$ with not much care for your approximation, the spectrum of $A|_W$ could be arbitrarily ugly, with many more points than what you had before. The example you have in the book is a minimal example that shows this feature, and it provides some intuition on the fact that the reason why the approximation $W$ generates the spurious eigenvalue is that $A(W)\not\subset W$, or in other words, $W$ “does not cut $A$ along the eigenspaces”: that is, even when you look for a basis of $W$ that diagonalizes $P’\circ A$, there is at least one element of the basis which must be written as a sum of two eigenvectors of $A$ (or more; you can try to think about why this has to be true if $A$ does not preserve $W$), and since the two eigenvectors belong to different eigenspaces, the basis vector is mapped into something that has “intermediate length” between the two eigenvalues, $0$ and $1$, hence the spurious eigenvalue coming from mixing two different states.

I guess that from here one needs to start developing more intuition, but this is relaly just the starting point for that, so you should not worry if you do not quite get the point. If you don’t see why this extra eigenvalue pops up, you could maybe try to see what happens if you try to modify the basis of $W_n$ to get rid of that extra eigenvalue.

Comment: Sorry, many edits. Now it’s readable